# How to order with an SQL array slice in Sequel?

Tags: ruby, sequel

What is the proper syntax in [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/) to order by a slice of an SQL array value?

Here's what I want to do in SQL:

```
SELECT
  a,                -- column with SQL array values
  depth,
  name
FROM
  nodes
ORDER BY
  a[0:depth], name  -- sort by 'a' ignoring last element, then by 'name'
```

In Sequel, I could do:

```
DB[:nodes].select(:a, :depth, :name).order(:a, :name)
```

but this sorts by all of `:a`, not the `[0:depth]` slice as desired.  What's the proper syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
DB[:nodes].select(:a, :depth, :name).order('a[0:depth]'.lit, :name)
```

Any better suggestions?

Comment: That looks like the best way.  Sequel's DSL has no support for the `[0:depth]` syntax.  You could do `:a.sql_subscript('0:depth'.lit)`, but that doesn't buy you much.